# hide div using javascripting DOM scripting depending on the sum of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, function, radio-button, hide

Good afternoon,
I want (as the title says)to hide my div tags depending on the sum of my radio buttons values. I cannot use query only DOM scripting
The code is quite long so I hope you could help me.
Thanks a lot

```
<body>

<script>    
function checkRadio() {
var selectedAge="";
var selectedBmi="";
var selectedDiabete="";
var description="";
var len = document.row.length;
var i;

function init(){
for (i = 0; i<len; i++) {
    if (document.row[i].value);
    break;
}

if (selectedAge == "") {
    document.getElementByid("radio_error").innnerHTML = "no option selected";
    return false
}
else {
        document.getElementById("radio_error").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
}

 }
init();

}

 </script>


 <script>
function addNumbers()
    {
var val1 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "selectedAge"]:checked').value);
var val2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "selectedBmi"]:checked').value);
var val3 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "selectedDiabete"]:checked').value);
var val4 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "description"]:checked').value);
var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");

ansD.value = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;
    }

 </script>

 <script>
 var myDiv=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
 var allDiv=myDiv.length;
 for(var i=0;i<allDiv.i++){
 currentDiv=myDiv[i];

 if (ansD.value<=15){
  div[0].style.display = 'block';
  div[1].style.display = 'none';
  div[2].style.display = 'none'
} else if (ansD.value<=25){
  div[0].style.display = 'none';
  div[1].style.display = 'block';
  div[2].style.display = 'none';
} else {ansD.value>25){
  div[0].style.display = 'none';
  div[1].style.display = 'none';
  div[2].style.display = 'block';
}

   </script>


        <table>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                            <th scope="col">noRisk</th>
                            <th scope="col">lowRisk</th>
                            <th scope="col">mediumRisk</th>
                            <th scope="col">HighRisk</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row"><div class="lefttext">How old are you?</div></th>

                            <td><input type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge" onclick="addNumber(val1)" value="0"checked>1-25</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge" onclick="addNumber(val1)" value="5">26-40</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge" onclick="addNumber(val1)" value="8">41-60</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge" onclick="addNumber(val1)" value="10">1-25</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row"><div class="lefttext">What is you BMI?</div></th>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" onclick="addNumber(val2)" value="0" checked>0-25</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" onclick="addNumber(val2)" value="0">26-30</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" onclick="addNumber(val2)" value="9">31-35</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" onclick="addNumber(val2)" value="10">35+</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row"><div class="lefttext">Does anybody in your family have diabetes?</div></th>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" onclick="addNumber(val3)" value="0" checked>No</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" onclick="addNumber(val3)" value="7">Grandparent</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" onclick="addNumber(val3)" value="15">Sibling</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" onclick="addNumber(val3)" value="15">Parent</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row"><div class="lefttext">How would you describe your diabete</div></th>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value4" name="description" onclick="addNumber(val4)" value="0" checked >Low sugar</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value4" name="description" onclick="addNumber(val4)" value="0">Normal sugar</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value4" name="description" onclick="addNumber(val4)" value="7">Quite high sugar</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="value4" name="description" onclick="addNumber(val4)" value="10">High sugar</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                     <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:addNumbers()"/>
                     Total  = <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" value=""/>



                <section>
                     <h2>Your results:</h2>
                    <div id="lowResult">
                            <p> Your results show that you currently have a low risk of
                            developing diabetes. However, it is important that you
                            maintain a healthy lifestyle in terms of diet and exercise.
                            </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="mediumResult">
                            <p>Your results show that you currently have a medium risk of
                               developing diabetes. For more information on your risk
                               factors, and what to do about them, please visit our diabetes
                               advice website at <a href="http://www.zha.org.zd">http://www.zha.org.zd</a>.
                            <p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="highRisk">
                            <p>Your results show that you currently have a HIGH risk of
                                developing diabetes. [Your main risk factors are your BMI and
                                your diet.] We advise that you contact the Health Authority to
                                discuss your risk factors as soon as you can. Please fill in our
                                contact form and a member of the Health Authority Diabetes
                                Team will be in contact with you.
                    </div>
                </section>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that all the div appears on the page and I want to hide them depending on the total returned with the submit button. for ex if total is less than 15 I want only the lowRisk div displayed on my html page

Comment: You stated that, but what is actually the issue here. What kind of output you get, what's the result of your code so far.

Comment: when I run the code all the div tag are displayed none are hidden

Comment: Can't find your var div array and your for queue is broken. for(var i=0;i<allDiv.i++) to for(var i=0;i<allDiv.length;i++){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed all unused code and left only addNumbers function. I have also removed events on each button - no such function.

I sum over all checked radio buttons so if you have other on the page you probably need more specific selector.

```js
function addNumbers() {
  var selectedRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedRadios.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(selectedRadios[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('answer').value = sum;
  var showDiv = sum < 15 ? "lowResult" : (sum < 25 ? "mediumResult" : "highRisk");
  document.getElementById(showDiv).style.display = 'block';

}
```

```css
.results {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <th scope="col"></th>
    <th scope="col">noRisk</th>
    <th scope="col">lowRisk</th>
    <th scope="col">mediumRisk</th>
    <th scope="col">HighRisk</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">
      <div class="lefttext">How old are you?</div>
    </th>

    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge" value="0" checked>1-25</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge" value="5">26-40</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge" value="8">41-60</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge" value="10">1-25</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th scope="row">
      <div class="lefttext">What is you BMI?</div>
    </th>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" value="0" checked>0-25</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" value="0">26-30</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" value="9">31-35</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" value="10">35+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">
      <div class="lefttext">Does anybody in your family have diabetes?</div>
    </th>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" value="0" checked>No</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" value="7">Grandparent</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" value="15">Sibling</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" value="15">Parent</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">
      <div class="lefttext">How would you describe your diabete</div>
    </th>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value4" name="description" value="0" checked>Low sugar</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value4" name="description" value="0">Normal sugar</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value4" name="description" value="7">Quite high sugar</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="value4" name="description" value="10">High sugar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:addNumbers()" />Total =
<input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" value="" />



<section>
  <h2>Your results:</h2>
  <div class="results" id="lowResult">
    <p>Your results show that you currently have a low risk of developing diabetes. However, it is important that you maintain a healthy lifestyle in terms of diet and exercise.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="results" id="mediumResult">
    <p>Your results show that you currently have a medium risk of developing diabetes. For more information on your risk factors, and what to do about them, please visit our diabetes advice website at <a href="http://www.zha.org.zd">http://www.zha.org.zd</a>.
      <p>
  </div>
  <div class="results" id="highRisk">
    <p>Your results show that you currently have a HIGH risk of developing diabetes. [Your main risk factors are your BMI and your diet.] We advise that you contact the Health Authority to discuss your risk factors as soon as you can. Please fill in our
      contact form and a member of the Health Authority Diabetes Team will be in contact with you.
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please test your code before submitting a question. If you test the code you can clearly see an error in the console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

You have several problems.

1)

```
for(var i=0;i<allDiv.i++){
```

There is a wrong dot. The code should be:

```
for(var i=0;i<allDiv;i++){
```

2)

```
} else {ansD.value>25){
```

Missing an IF and (. Should be:

```
} else if (ansD.value>25){
```

3)

Also, this for is not closed:

```
for(var i=0;i<allDiv;i++){
 currentDiv=myDiv[i];
```

Should be:

```
for(var i=0;i<allDiv;i++){
 currentDiv=myDiv[i];
 }
```

4)

Then i get that the function addNumber does not exist but I believe that is because you have an external script loading that function. If you modify that, then the code will work.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addNumber is not definedonclick @ test.html:100
```

Cheers

EDIT:

It will be easier to just rewrite the code. Here, use this function instead of addNumbers on the submit and lose the addNumber. It should be better if you remove the style display as soon as you load the page. Study the function to see how it works.

```
<script>

  function showResult(){

    var val1 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "selectedAge"]:checked').value);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "selectedBmi"]:checked').value);
    var val3 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "selectedDiabete"]:checked').value);
    var val4 = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "description"]:checked').value);
    var result = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;

    var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
    ansD.value = result;

    var divLow = document.getElementById("lowResult");
    var divMedium = document.getElementById("mediumResult");
    var divHigh = document.getElementById("highRisk");

    divLow.style.display = 'none';
    divMedium.style.display = 'none';
    divHigh.style.display = 'none';

    if (result < 15){
        divLow.style.display = 'block';
    } else if (result < 25){
        divMedium.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        divHigh.style.display = 'block';
    } 

    console.log(result);

   }  

   </script>
```

Comment: Sorry I am new in javascript thank you for your advice but it does not work.I set the property display to none in my css for the div tag. So none appears on my html now even with the code..

Comment: See the Edited answer. There you have the function. You were over complicating the issue.